# how to throw an exception to the main method consist of arraylist?

Tags: java

/*Create a method namely callMethod in which display all countries from the arraylist,If more than 5 countries,the method will throw an exception to the main() method*/

import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.List;

import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Countries {

```
static List<String> country = Arrays.asList("Singapore", "America", "France","Japan","China","UK","Indonesia","India");

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ListIterator<String> myListIterator = country.listIterator();
    while (myListIterator.hasNext()) {

        System.out.print(myListIterator.next() + " ");


    }
    System.out.println();

    Countries countries = new Countries();
    countries.callMethod();
}

public void callMethod() {
    try {
       System.out.println(country.get(6));
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("Maximum countries is 5");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your method with something like

```
public void callMethod() {
        if (null!=country && country.size() > 5) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Maximum countries allowed are 5");
        }
    }
```

you can catch the error by wrapping `callMethod` invocation call with `try{...}catch(){}`

```
try {
      countries.callMethod();
    } catch (RuntimeException rex) {
      rex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks sir,It works! May i know how to catch it as well?

Comment: Updated the ans @Elvis for exception handling

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to realise whether should you throw an Exception or catch it. Suppose an exception occurs in a function f. Should f *handle* that, or pass it to the parent function?

Once you are ready with the answer, the approach is as follows.

If f can handle that exception, write the piece of code in a try-catch block. Similar to the above case.

Otherwise, just declare the function saying it may throw an exception.

```
public void callMethod() throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if(country.size()>=6)
         throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("country size should be less than 6");
    System.out.println(country.get(6));
}
```

Now, put the call to **callMethod()** in a try-catch block in the main function.

You can go through [this document](https://howtodoinjava.com/best-practices/java-exception-handling-best-practices/) for a deeper dive into exception handling best practices in Java.